# How to restrict access to particular rows in django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I am using Django Admin Tool and I have very simple model. I want to restrict access to particular password for specific user or specific group. How can I make 3 condition for access 'Yes/No/Never' and when user has got Yes + his group No then he's got access but when Yes + Never then not. And how can I make it working with django-admin-tools permissions system.

```
from django.db import models
from passwords.objects.labels.models import Label

class Password(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'passwords'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    labels = models.ManyToManyField(Label)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, django only supports class-level permissions (in other words, permissions on the *table*).

There is support for object-level (row level) permissions, but django doesn't come with it implemented out of the box:

> Object-level permissions
>
> A foundation for specifying permissions at the per-object level has
>   been added. Although there is no implementation of this in core, a
>   custom authentication backend can provide this implementation and it
>   will be used by django.contrib.auth.models.User. See the
>   authentication docs for more information.

Consequently, there are third party apps like [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) that enable this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with the admin, you can override the `has_add_permission`, `has_change_permission` and `has_delete_permission` methods on `ModelAdmin`. But, I can't really help you further without knowing how your "Yes/No/Never" permissions are attached to the user/group.

**UPDATE**

If you want to keep it stupidly simple, the best way would be to simply create a group, "PasswordAccess" for example. Then, assign any users you want to that group, and only assign the default add, change and delete permissions for `Password` to that group.

Nothing else is required. Any user added to that group will automatically inherit the permissions for `Password`, any other user won't have those permissions and therefore won't even see it in the admin.

Comment: Thanks so much for help guys, Yes/No/Never is probably overcomplicating especially i'm just starting learning Python, so how can i set Yes/No so any User must have or individual permission or must be in group that have permission to read password.